# Disabling a button after a button click and reenabling it after a process is over

Tags: c#, ajax

I am trying to call a controller method which will generate from a cshtml page. While the controller is performing the action, the button must remain disbled and must only be enabled after the entire process is complete. Now the button gets disabled but it does not enable after the process is complete. Also if you refresh the page, even if the process is still going on the button gets enabled which should not happen Is there any help on how I can acheive this?

.cshtml file

```
function generate()
{
    $('generate').attr('disabled',true);
    alert('Process started')
    var date=$(#ReportFromDate).val();
    $ajax({
        url:@Url.Content("Home/GenerateReport"),
        type:"POST",
        data:{ReportFromDate:date},
        traditional:true,
        success:function(response) {
            //alert()
        }
    });
};
```

this is where I am calling the above ajax call

```
<input name="generate" id="generate" type="button" value="generate" onclick="generate">
```

Controller file

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Report()
{
   var reportModel= new ReportModel;
   return View("Report",reportModel)
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateReport()
{
   this.repository.generateReport(model);
   return View("Report");
}
```

Comment: Where have you written the code to re-enable the button?

Comment: After the method  this.repository.generateReport(model) is completed the view is returned, shouldnt the new view be the one with enabled button? @PriyankPanchal

Comment: You are calling `GenerateReport()` using an ajax call, so `return View()` will not work as expected. The ajax call expects a JSON in return. Once JSON is returned, you can enable the button in ajax `success` callback. You will have to restructure your code for this for which none of us would be able to help much with given information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you disable button before sending request, but don't enable it after finishing ajax request. To do so, you should use `$('generate').removeAttr('disabled')` inside `success` and also `error` event of your ajax request.

Note: Also `$('generate')` is not correct and you should access element with class with `.` prefix or id with `#` prefix.